# What is the definition of a data factory in ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory

What is the definition of a *data factory* in Azure Data Factory? The precise definition has proved elusive in my research. The term gets thrown around a lot but I can't find an instance where it's explicitly nailed down.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes in the context of Azure, the ADF resource itself is called a "data factory". Like in OOP, imagine it as an object (data factory) created from a class (Azure Data Factory). You can have multiple objects from the same class.

Hope this helped!